# Module Resolution without Extension

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Given this line in index.jsx:

```
import ExampleTable from 'table';
```

I'm getting:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'table' in global-path-to/application/public/scripts
>    @ ./application/public/scripts/index.jsx 19:13-29

But table.jsx lives in that folder and I've attempted to define the file extensions in webpack.config.js:

```
{
entry:SOURCE_DIRECTORY + '/index.jsx',

output:
{
    path:SCRIPT_DIRECTORY,
    filename:'bundle.js'
},

resolve:
{
    extensions:['', '.js', '.jsx']
},    

module:
{
    loaders:
    [
        {
            // Regular expression to find both .js and .jsx files.
            test:/\.jsx?$/,
            include:SCRIPT_DIRECTORY,
            loader: 'babel'
        }
    ]
}
};
```

---

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
├── babel-core@6.7.7
├── babel-loader@6.2.4
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.6.0
├── babel-preset-react@6.5.0
├── jquery@2.2.3
├── jsx-loader@0.13.2
├── material-ui@0.15.0-beta.2
├── react@15.0.1
├── react-dom@15.0.1
├── react-tap-event-plugin@1.0.0
└── webpack@1.13.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use the relative path, `./table`, otherwise it tries to look up a `table` package in node_modules.

If you have more complex paths, you could also set up path resolvers in the webpack config: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root